# Limit Navigation Controller to a set of UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

[image]

Is it possible to limit the NavigationController to a certain set of UIViewControllers. See the image, I want the navigation controller, but only for the login/create user session. Once logged in, I obviously don't want the user to be able to go back (except log out). How can I accomplish that? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not present your login controller over your actual root view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Storyboard -> select NavigationController -> Attributes Inspector -> uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" property

Then select relationship between Login/SignUp And TabBarController, and delete it.

Once login you can set your TabBarController(or any related controller) as the rootViewController. And when app launches you can check it in your `AppDelegate.swift` file like this,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! TabBarController
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else
    {
        let loginNavController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginNavController") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginNavController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change the stack of your navigation controller when needed, e.g:

```
func logIn() {
   //Delete all presented view controllers up to a point
   navigationController.setViewControllers([], animated: false)

   //Create new view controller
   let viewController = ....
   navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Take a look at [setViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers), that may give you some idea.

If you want to leave previous view controllers in stack, and just forbid user to pop to them, then it may be the best solution to subclass UINavigationController and override `func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController?`

Comment: There is no need to remove controllers, you can just call `navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: true)` directly.

Comment: All I did now was set "Show" to "Present modally". That unbound the rest of the Controllers from the navigation controller!